# Flask: get absolute URL of the route with args

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to Flask. I would like to get route's URL for JavaScript processing. Here's my route:

```
@bp.route('/')
@bp.route('/foo/<path:segments>')
def langing_page(segments=''):
    url_pattern= # here I don't know what to do
    return render_template('bts/article.html', url_pattern=url_pattern)
```

I would like to pass a value like `http://mysite.test/foo/%s` as `url_pattern` for my view. In other words, just to keep the `/foo` prefix in one place.

Can that be achieved or should i just use `/foo` in a variable?

Comment: Browser side url pattern cannot be controlled through flask. The user sent request to this route endpoint by visiting "/foo/<some-segments>" and that's exactly how it'd be displayed when response is returned to the browser. Why do you want to change that?

Comment: That's not what I meant. I have a Single Page App using History API. On client side, I need to generate some links that will point to this `/foo/%s` endpoint. So for example, I will pass a value `http://mysite.test/foo/%s` to JavaScript and then dynamically create URLs like `bar/baz` => `http://mysite.test/foo/bar/baz` in my app on the client side.

Comment: Of course mixing server side and client side like that is not that common, but my app needs to handle disabled JS, so it will render on the server side when JS is down.

Comment: If you are so inclined, then yes, you can pass that "foo" as named argument to the `render_template()`, which you can catch in the html using jinja2 convention, something like this: `<a href="/{{url_pattern}}/test">The Link</a>`

Comment: I'm doing something even better, just replacing the `%s`, so my URL can also have a suffix, like: `/foo/%s/bar`.

Comment: Its better for updating only a single variable, yeah. But jinja templating is helpful in the long run for doing extra stuff (like looping through a python list and fill an html list, display widgets based on session variables, etc).

Comment: I know that, but I don't see how it's related.

Answer (score 0):

To get the absolute url of an html page, or route in Python's Flask framework use: `request.build_absolute_uri`

where `request` is a Python module acquired with:

`from flask import request`